# Swift prefix() without being invoked on an object

Tags: swift

I have seen this code in a video-tutorial:

```
extension String {
    func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
      return prefix(1).uppercased() + self.lowercased().dropFirst()
    }

    mutating func capitalizeFirstLetter() {
      self = self.capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}
```

It shall capitalize a string. E.g. "john" becomes "John".

It works just fine. But I don't understand how the code works.

prefix() isn't invoked upon a string. **How does it know from which data it shall return the first element?**

**What't the purpose of the mutating function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return `prefix(1)...` is the same as `return self.prefix(1)...`, the expression is called on `self`

In the example `john.capitalizingFirstLetter()` `self` is `john`.

And the mutating function is similar to `sort` and `sorted`, once the value is modified in place and once the modified value is returned.